# What is the correct xpath for getting this data?

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to access values within some html, but I can't get the xpath right.

I have tried several xpath tutorials, looked at several stackoverflow responses as well, and of course trial and error. I am missing something important.

Here is what the path looks like roughly:

```
div id='container' class='container' role='main'
    div class = 'row-fluid'>
        div class = 'col-md-12'
            div id = 'canvas
                div id = 'Error' class = 'error' align = 'center' </div>
                div id = 'subcanvas'
                    div id = 'w-box' class = 'grid-stack-instance-9644' [etc..]
                        div id = 'widget1' class = 'panel panel-default' style  = 'overflow: initial !important;'
                            div class = 'grid-stack-item-content cell'
                                table id = 'RptGrowthStatistics' class ='table stoff table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive etc...
                                    <thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td nowrap='nowrap' class='L0'>
                                                <a>South San Francisco</a>
                                            <td/>
                                            <!---->
                                            <td class="Right">5,437</td>
                                            <td class="Right">282.78</td>
                                            <td class="Right">4.36</td>
                                            <td class="Right">3,573</td>
                                            <!---->
                                            <td class="Right">3,354</td>
                                            <td class="Right">5,737</td>
                                            <td class="Right">6,680</td>
                                            <td class="Right">876.07</td>
```

I am trying to get to that td class = where you have "South San Francisco" listed as well as any other td values. That's the data I want. I've tried variations of

```
xpath(//table[@id="RptRoomStats"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a)
```

that have no success.

I can get down to {'id' : 'subcanvas'} but am unable to get past that point

```
# gives {'id': 'Error', 'class': 'error', 'align': 'center'}
x = tree.xpath(".//form[@name]/div[5]/div/div/div/div")
print(x[0].attrib)
```

Comment: You should fix your html first; many opening and closing tags are missing.

Comment: agree with above. Maybe `tidy` can help, but be ready for experimentation time there as well. AND your query doesn't match your data, i.e. data=`RptGrowthStatistics` not `RptRoomStats`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below xpath.

```
//table[@id="RptGrowthStatistics"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]